# HTML to produce hanging indent when pasting into Microsoft Word

Tags: html, css, ms-word, indentation, text-indent

I'm creating a webpage that produces formatted text, which is then copy&pasted into Microsoft Word 2010. Everything works fine, except I have to support hanging indent. The method I found to produce hanging indent using CSS with `margin-left: 1cm; text-indent: -1cm;`. This works fine on the page, but doesn't work when copied over to word, as the `margin-left` part is lost.

Thus, the beginning lines of all paragraphs are shifted left, instead of all others being shifted right.

Example (put into a HTML file, then copy from Firefox to Word):

```
<div style="margin-left: 1cm; text-indent: -1cm;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Vestibulum eu nunc ut nunc dictum molestie.
Ut et porttitor leo, at tincidunt neque. 
Integer vulputate sed odio nec aliquam.</div>
```

**Edit**: Fixed typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-answer, as I figured it out after I'd already written the question.

The key is to use a `p` tag instead of a `div`. Then it works, for whatever reason. If you want to test it yourself, check out the [demo](http://greek0.net/div/http-hanging-indent.html) I've written up.

```
<p style="margin-left: 1cm; text-indent: -1cm;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Vestibulum eu nunc ut nunc dictum molestie.
Ut et porttitor leo, at tincidunt neque. 
Integer vulputate sed odio nec aliquam.</p>
```